# How to load a table on a cell by cell basis

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple table with a link and an image in a div in each cell. the simplified code is like:

```
<td>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <div>
        <img src="image01.jpg" />
    </div>
</td>
```

I pull the values for the link and the image from a the database and manually generate the table like:

```
cell = "<td>"
       + "<a href=\"#\"></a><div>"
       + "<img src=\"" + imageName + "\" "
       + "\" alt=\"" + imageName + "\" /></div></td>";
```

When the user hovers the images, another image element is displayed to show a bigger version of the hovered image. This is done with javascript.

To be able to instantly respond to the hover, I actually load the bigger versions of the images in the table. I resize and crop them (hence the parent divs).

Since the table has around 40-100 cells, and the images vary between 180px to 800px width, I decided to load the empty table first, and then refresh the page with each cell content. This way the user will be able to interact with the loaded images, while the rest is still loading.

I think it is possible with an ajax loop that fires upon each page load with a counter set to the total number of cells. But I do not know how it can be done.

Is there a way to load the content of a cell, display it to the user and go on loadind the next cells?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you're doing this kind of HTML generation client side you should take a look at jQuery templating support.  If you're doing it server side a better practice would be to use some sort of a repeating control (like [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx)) and generate your markup that way.  You can still have all of the control you want over how the images and links are generated.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, thank you. I took your advice and went for the repeater control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in javascript, with a help from [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) to make the code cleaner.

The HTML you'll load have the image names on the `data-src` attribute, while the `src` is a blank file you should provide in your server (here, named `blank.gif`):

```
<td><img src='blank.gif' 
     style='width:100px;height:100px' 
     data-src='imagename.jpg' /></td>
```

This should be produced by the code:

```
cell = "<td><img src='blank.gif' style='width:" + imageWidth + 
        "px;" + imageHeight + "px' data-src='" + imageName + "' /></td>";
```

Providing the width and height is optional. If you can have then beforehand, the effect will be nicer. If you can't, the table will take shape only when the images are loading.

Finally, to load the contents, use the following script somewhere in your HTML:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        var src=$(this).data("src"); //retrieve the data-src attribute
        if (src) $(this).attr("src", src); // if present, load the image
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: thank you Ariel, I tried your solution and it seems to work. Still, the images are being loaded in a random order. Do you know a way to call them in the order they appear in the table?

Comment: The only way i can think of is put a small delay between each assignment. If you want, write another question and i show. (or someone else ;)